# macOS NSTabViewController centered tab icons

Tags: swift, macos, nstabviewcontroller

I have a macOS app I have created. And I have a Preferences window built using a swift & storyboard with a tabless Toolbar styled NSTabViewController.

I see no way to override the positioning of the tab icons though - they default to the left side of the window.
Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass `NSTabViewController` and override `func toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier]`. Add a `flexibleSpace` toolbar item at both sides.

Comment: that was super easy! thanks. ill post ,my particular solution below as it may help others

Answer (score 1):

following **Willeke**'s tip, I came up with this override in my `NSTabViewController` subclass:

```
override func toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {

    super.toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(toolbar)

    var arr = Array<NSToolbarItem.Identifier>()
    for item in self.tabViewItems {
        if let identifier = item.identifier {
            arr.append(NSToolbarItem.Identifier.init(identifier as! String))
        }
    }

    //insert flexible spaces at first and last index
    arr.insert(NSToolbarItem.Identifier.flexibleSpace, at: 0)
    arr.append(NSToolbarItem.Identifier.flexibleSpace)

    return arr
}
```

Comment: Why not just `var arr = super.toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(toolbar)`?

Answer (score 0):

OC:

```
-(NSArray<NSToolbarItemIdentifier> *)toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar{
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[super toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers:toolbar] mutableCopy];
    [arr insertObject:[[NSToolbarItem alloc] initWithItemIdentifier:NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItemIdentifier].itemIdentifier atIndex:0];
    [arr addObject:[[NSToolbarItem alloc] initWithItemIdentifier:NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItemIdentifier].itemIdentifier];
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift：

```
override func toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {
    var array = super.toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(toolbar)
    array.insert(NSToolbarItem.Identifier.flexibleSpace, at: 0)
    array.append(NSToolbarItem.Identifier.flexibleSpace)
    return array
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).